# BULK UPLOAD ERROR "errorThe given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column."

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, sqlbulkcopy

I am trying to import data from CSV to DataBase usingBulkUpload, I am able to copy columns which are varchar but I am not able to import when I try to import "Department's" data into Usertale.

---

Error:The given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column.

---

[Database Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ToN0n.png)

[Usertable Screenshot upload from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FzDo.png)

[MY Excel file which need to import](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5I8l.png)

```
      public ActionResult ImportFromExcel(HttpPostedFileBase postedFile)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (postedFile != null && postedFile.ContentLength > (1024 * 1024 * 50))  // 50MB limit  
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("postedFile", "Your file is to large. Maximum size allowed is 50MB !");
                }

                else
                {
                    string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                    {
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                    }

                    string filePath = path + Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                    string extension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName);
                    postedFile.SaveAs(filePath);

                    string conString = string.Empty;
                    switch (extension)
                    {
                        case ".xls": //For Excel 97-03.  
                            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                            break;
                        case ".xlsx": //For Excel 07 and above.  
                            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                            break;
                    }

                    try
                    {
                        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                        conString = string.Format(conString, filePath);

                        using (OleDbConnection connExcel = new OleDbConnection(conString))
                        {
                            using (OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new OleDbCommand())
                            {
                                using (OleDbDataAdapter odaExcel = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                                {
                                    cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;

                                    //Get the name of First Sheet.  
                                    connExcel.Open();
                                    DataTable dtExcelSchema;
                                    dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                                    string sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                              
                                    connExcel.Close();

                                    //Read Data from First Sheet.  
                                    connExcel.Open();
                                    cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";

                                    odaExcel.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
                                    odaExcel.Fill(dt);
                                    connExcel.Close();
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SLOT_TESTING_DB"].ConnectionString;
                        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                        {
                            con.Open();
                            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
                            {
                                //Set the database table name.  
                                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "UserTables";
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("User_id", "User_id");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Email", "Email");
                                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("UserType", "UserType");

                          
                               sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Department_Name", "DepartmentId");


                                //int dptname = sqlBulkCopy.ParseInt();
                                //sqlBulkCopy.DepartmentId.tryParseToDepartment_Name();

                                //sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("TermId", "TermId");

                                //Int32.TryParse(Department.Text, out int x);
                                //Convert.ToInt64("Department_Name");
                                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                                Response.Write("Bulk data stored successfully");
                                Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully");


                            }
                        }
                    }

                    //catch (Exception ex)  
                    //{  
                    //    throw ex;  
                    //}  
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        return Json("error" + e.Message);
                    }
                    //return RedirectToAction("Index");  
                }
            }
            //return View(postedFile);  
            return Json("File uploaded successfully");
            //Console.WriteLine("File uploaded successfully");
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for the column DepartmentId? Also I would suggest changing SELECT * FROM to explicitly specify only the columns you need. You might have problems if your query is returning a column called Department_Name.

Comment: sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Department_Name", "DepartmentId"); suggests you are trying to insert a string (Department Name) into an int (DepartmentId). This would be consistent with the error you are seeing. Trying mapping DepartmentId to DepartmentId instead and inserting those values into your UserTable.

Comment: i have update the details above please check

Comment: Thanks openshac but still it gives same error "errorThe given value of type String from the data source cannot be converted to type int of the specified target column."

Comment: if i give interger values in Department_Name column like e.g 123, it saves successfully. but not on strings

Comment: Yes that is because you are inserting into the table UserTables which has the column DepartmentId. This is an INT column right? As you know, you can't insert a string into an INT column. The error you would get is exactly the error you are seeing.

Comment: Yessss exactly you got the pointt...... i have to match the id but how should I work on this scenario.

Comment: Try this accepted answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380621/how-to-use-bulk-insert-when-rows-depend-on-foreign-keys-values Using a staging tables seems like a good idea. Otherwise you are going to need to add DepartmentId to your Excel sheet.

Comment: yes i am looking on that article sir and thanks

Comment: Secondly, Is there any possibility to compare the string value (the column name which is in string) and check what id is in the database. and then enter. Is there something like that?

Comment: Yes sure, just join on the Departments table when you are copying from the Staging table to the UserTable. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/686670/283787.

Comment: SIR, So nice of you... i got that

Comment: Great, so is it working now for you?

Comment: Nope :(, this scenario is new for me it taking much time for the Staging table creation.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp fro an example. It will probably be very similar to the script you are using to create the UserTable